# how to type a function that returns None if input is string otherwise return the input as is

Tags: python, mypy, type-annotation

I wonder what's the right way to type annotate a python function as below?

```
def f(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return None
    return value
```

This is a toy example that is analogous to a python I encountered that needs type annotated. Using `Union` like

```
def f(value: Union[float, int, str]) -> Union[float, int, None]:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return None
    return value
```

doesn't feel right because it doesn't enforce the rules

- an `int` input must result in an `int` output.
- a `float` input must result in a `float` output.
- a `str` input must result in `None`.

Let's assume the input can only be one of `int/float/str`.

Comment: Have you considered a [pydantic model](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) or [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) to narrow the types of return values based on the types of the arguments:

```
from typing import overload

@overload
def f(value: str) -> None: ...

@overload
def f(value: int) -> int: ...

@overload
def f(value: float) -> float: ...

def f(value: int|float|str) -> int|float|None:
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return None
    return value
```

Note that the actual implementation uses a union of all the possible argument and return types.

If a call to the function conforms to one of the overload stubs, the appropriate return type is inferred:

```
reveal_type(f("foo"))  # revealed type is "None"
reveal_type(f(123))    # revealed type is "builtins.int"
```